# retrieving row value when multiple rows share same id

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
var rowId = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");

var writer = jQuery('#reportList').jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'writer');
```

I set 'key:true' to 'num' column inside 'colModel'
and the values of 'num' are from mySql

I'm trying to retrieve writer with the code above when clicking a row

However,  because some of rows share same id, the wrong information is stored in 'writer'.

In this case, is there any way to distinguish the row and get correct value even if some rows share same id???

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

In order everything to work properly with jqGrid the id of every row should have unique value. Duplicate id will cause a lot of problems.

Be a sure you have set a unique value of every row.

In case when two or more grids have the same row id it is recommended to use the idPrefix see [Guriddo jqGrid docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options)  (which should be unique for every grid)